# 'stuff' subcommand not effective in 'screen' session until it has been attached

Tags: command-line, bash, utilities

In macOS Catalina 10.15.7, screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06:

I'm attempting to use the 'screen' command (/usr/bin/screen) to run a program in the background. I create a detached screen session to run my program, then I use screen's 'stuff' subcommand to send the program a command. But the program never sees that command.

If I attach to the session and then detach, 'stuff' works as I expect.

How can I make 'screen' forward the command to the program without attaching first? This is used to spin up a number of processes without user intervention, so attaching and stealing the terminal focus is not an option.

Here's a minimal example:

```
# Create the detached screen session
screen -dmS test /bin/bash
# Send it a command to execute
screen -r test -X stuff "$(printf "%s\r" 'whoami')"
# Attach to the session to see if the command has executed (type control-A d to detach)
screen -r test
# Send the same command again
screen -r test -X stuff "$(printf "%s\r" 'whoami')"
# Attach again and see that the second command has executed
screen -r test
```

(Note: I sent this to Ask Different because Apple uses a very old version of 'screen' which AFAIK is not used on any other platform.)

Comment: It seems this problem is not unique to macOS screen, as a search turned up a similar problem at linuxquestions: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/gnu-screen-send-stuff-command-to-detached-screen-session-923822/

Answer (score 1):

The answer was found on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/342463/gnu-screen-cant-stuff-commands-unless-the-screen-is-attached

> When you start a Screen session in detached mode (screen -d -m), no window is selected, so input later sent with screen -X stuff is just lost. You need to explicitly specify that you want to send the keystrokes to window 0 (-p 0). This is a good idea anyway, in case you happen to create other windows in that Screen session for whatever reason.

e.g.

```
screen -r test -p 0 -X stuff "$(printf "%s\r" 'whoami')"
```